# Macro for NSLocalizedString not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, nslocalizedstring

I build a Macro for NSLocalizedString like this in my Prefix.pch:

```
#undef NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key,_comment) [[LocalizedText sharedInstance] localizedStringFor:key]
```

My `LocalizedText` class looks like this:

```
+ (LocalizedText *)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (_singletonInstance == nil)
            _singletonInstance = [[LocalizedText alloc] init];
    }

    return _singletonInstance;
}

- (NSString *) localizedStringFor:(NSString*) key
{

    NSUserDefaults *deviceLanguage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   NSString *currentLanguage = [deviceLanguage objectForKey:@"deviceLanguage"];

    NSString *path;
    if([currentLanguage isEqual: @"en"])
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    else if([currentLanguage isEqual: @"de"])
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"de" ofType:@"lproj"];
    else if([currentLanguage isEqual: @"it"])
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"it" ofType:@"lproj"];


    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];

    return str;

}
```

So for example, when i change my `NSUserDefaults` to `@"en"`, i expect that every `NSLocalizedString` gives me the correct english translation, but it never changes and is always the default language. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Before debugging your Macro, I would set up a test as follows:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *currentLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"deviceLanguage"];

NSString *key = @"SomeKeyFromYourLocalizedFile";
NSString *localized = [[LocalizedText sharedInstance] localizedStringFor:key];
NSLog(@"%@: %@", currentLanguage, localized);

[defaults setObject:@"de" forKey:@"deviceLanguage"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSString *localized = [[LocalizedText sharedInstance] localizedStringFor:key];
NSLog(@"%@: %@", currentLanguage, localized);

[defaults setObject:@"it" forKey:@"deviceLanguage"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSString *localized = [[LocalizedText sharedInstance] localizedStringFor:key];
NSLog(@"%@: %@", currentLanguage, localized);
```

And see the output of that. Your bug is probably somewhere in there.

I expect:

```
en: English localized
de: German localized
it: Italian localized
```

After that, you would simply use your macro (which looks like it will work just like that). I tried:

```
#ifdef NSLocalizedString
#undef NSLocalizedString
#endif
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) NSLog(@"Output %@, %@", key, comment)

NSLocalizedString(@"First", @"Second");
```

Which results in:
`2017-01-12 14:31:31.501 App[49000:50650596] Output First, Second`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems the "[[LocalizedText sharedInstance] localizedStringFor:key]" works perfectly, but when i try to use the macro the function is not getting called, so it seems a Problem with the marco it self.

Comment: That's weird! I tried the same and that _does_ work. Please see the updated answer.